# How to create a floating search box for macOS

Tags: swift, macos

How can I create a floating search box for macOS using Swift like Spotlight and Alfred?

[image: Alfred search box]

Comment: It's just a window without a title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use ScalaFX for this purpose

```
object Main extends JFXApp {
  val resource = getClass.getResource("/box.fxml")
  val root = FXMLView(resource, new GuiceDependencyResolver())

  stage = new PrimaryStage() {
    initStyle(StageStyle.Undecorated) // this option removes the default header
    title = "Cats"
    scene = new Scene(root)
  }
}
```